# rpm in my car drops very quickly to idle when I foot off accelaration peddle

Tags: toyota, vios

I have a toyota vios 2003. When I accelerate my car(when driving at certain speed say 20km/h it accelerates lets say up to 60km/h but when I take my foot off from acceleration paddle rpm drops very quickly(~1000 which is normally the rpm when idle) and feels loosing the speed abruptly. I remember this was not like before. I recently replaced fuel filter and fuel pressure pump.  Is this normal or indicates a problem?

Comment: Are you talking about when the vehicle is stationary or when it is driving? when in neutral & stationary this sounds like expected behavior, you increase throttle the engine revs up, you remove throttle the engine goes back to idle. What are you expecting, out of curiosity?

Comment: What you are describing is exactly what should happen, I expect you know what but simply haven't stated the problem completely. If you could expand a bit that would help

Comment: Is this a manual or automatic transmission? @JamesTrotter He mentions losing speed, so I would assume it's while driving.

Comment: @JamesTrotter This is a auto transmission vehicle it happens when driving.

Comment: Maybe your calipers are sticking and when you let off the brake, the sticking caliper is slightly pressing the brake pad against the rotor? Have you changed brakes any lately? Can you look at your rotors and see if they are heat checked or have heat spots on them?

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT I have not changed break pads recently and they looks good to me also service guy last week said they are good to go for another ~10000km.  I will check the rotor..This can also cause sudden 'rpm drops?

Comment: When you press the brakes that slows the car and thus the RPMs of the tires rolling the car (or at least gives it that feel). I would say yes, if the brakes are dragging (even slightly) due to a CALIPER sticking which is the mechanism that presses the brake pads against the rotor when you stop, it will have a similar effect. Sometimes when you change the pads the little floating pin may need to be changed or at least lubed and confirmed it moves or that can cause similar issues.

Comment: I'd just be sure to rule out the simple stuff first basically... Just an idea!!

Comment: @ PIMP_JUICE_IT Hmm yeah, I have checked rotors they do not have heat spots and looks good to me as far as I can check.. Between I do not hear any freaky sounds or vibrations when breaking... not sure about caliper checking though, may be I will check them when changing break pads...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be throttle body calibration issue. I did a engine tuneup recently and cleaned up throttle body for carbon residue. After calibrating throttle body sudden rpm drops has not been observed so far at least in test drive..

Comment: Good information; glad you fixed it!!